# How to get sibling selector checking if a checkbox is checked in SASS working

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I realized that I am not correctly stating the issue. The issue I'm having is when clicking on the hamburger the menu will not open. I think it might be how the sibling selectors are coded. If I display the checkbox in `.cc_menu-btn` and click that, then the menu opens. Am I missing something or is it my selectors?

```
.cc_headernav {

  .cc_menu-btn {
    display: none;

    &:hover {
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
    }
  }

  .cc_menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;

    .navicon {
      background: #009FAE;
      display: block;
      height: 4px;
      position: relative;
      transition: background .2s ease-out;
      width: 30px;

      &:before {
        background: #009FAE;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        transition: all .2s ease-out;
        width: 100%;
        top: 9px;
      }
      &:after {
        background: #009FAE;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        transition: all .2s ease-out;
        width: 100%;
        top: -9px;
      }
    }
  }
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .cc_menu {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;

    li {

      a {
        display: block;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
        text-decoration: none;

        &:hover {
          background-color: #f4f4f4;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// CSS Need to Make SASSY

.cc_menu-btn:checked ~ .cc_menu {
  max-height: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px #c0c0c0;
}

.cc_menu-btn:checked + .cc_menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.cc_menu-btn:checked + .cc_menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.cc_menu-btn:checked + .cc_menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.cc_menu-btn:checked + .cc_menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.cc_menu-btn:checked + .cc_menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}
```

**HTML/JSX:**

```
<Column small={1} className="cc_headernav">
   <input className="cc_menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
   <label className="cc_menu-icon" for="cc_menu-btn"><span className="navicon"></span></label>
   <ul className="cc_menu">
     <li><Link name="Menu One" to="/MenuOne" onClick={this.changeTitle.bind(this)}>Menu One</Link></li>
     <li><Link name="Menu Two" to="/MenuTwo" onClick={this.changeTitle.bind(this)}>Menu Two</Link></li>
     <li><Link name="Menu Three" to="/Menu Three" onClick={this.changeTitle.bind(this)}>Menu Three</Link></li>
   </ul>
 </Column>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a full snippet with your markup in order to help?Thanks.

Comment: You have no sass specific stuff in any of your CSS? You need to post your HTML if this isn't working.

Comment: I'm going to edit the question with all the SASS and the HTML. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, `~` is the general sibling selector, not the adjacent sibling selector. Second, have you tried `.cc_menu-btn:checked { & ~ .cc_menu {}`?

Comment: @TylerH thanks for your help. Ok, so you are right, not adjacent. I'll fix that. But I have tried your approach of `.cc_menu-btn:checked { & ~ .cc_menu }` and that didn't work. The weird thing is that the `+` works on the other CSS but they were `~` and they didn't work like that. Now that they are `+` they work. So I'm stumped.

Comment: @TuckerJones That's odd; running `.cc_menu-btn:checked { & ~ .cc_menu { background: blue; } }` on Sassmeister.com shows it compiling to `.cc_menu-btn:checked ~ .cc_menu { background: blue; }`, which is correct.

Comment: The assumption now is that your HTML is incorrect. Obviously `className=` is not valid HTML, but it looks like you're using JSX, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @TylerH yea it has me baffled. I am using JSX cause this is a react project. I wonder if it's an issue with that.

Comment: @TylerH so you are correct. I realized my description was off. I changed that above.